# How to check if selected  index of dropdownlist is not 0 or -1 using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to check if selected  index of dropdownlist is not 0 or -1 using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to check to see if selected index was greater than 0, so I used:

```
if($("select option:selected").index() > 0) {
  alert($("select option:selected").index());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unless you've the actual `option` element to your hands, jQuery doesn't have special facilities for this. Just access the element's standard [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL:Property:selectedIndex) attribute:

```
var selectedIndex = $('#dropdownId').attr('selectedIndex');
if (selectedIndex > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Umm don't you mean `$('#dropdownId').get(0).selectedIndex` or `$('#dropdownId').attr('selectedIndex')` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$("select#elem").get(0).selectedIndex > 0
```

Comment: @pointy I don't see any difference from what i posted to what you commented to BalusC

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different approach from the others, jQuery can check the "value" of the option, as well.

```
<select id="checkme">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="-1">-1</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var theValue = $("#checkme").val();
    alert("The value of the select is: " + theValue);

});
```

This way you don't have to know what index maps to what value, you just check the value of the `select`, and it will tell you what `option` is selected.